# Routing tables with two network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

When I try to access the internet with my raspberry pi via ethernet, it works, but when I do `ifdown eth0` and try to ping any server **outside** my home network, it tells me

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Output of `route -n` (with eth0 enabled):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Output of `route -n` (with eth0 disabled):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

It looks like the gateway is only configured for eth0 and not for my wireless adapter.

I looked on the internet and got it to work by typing `sudo route add default gw 192.168.178.1`, but I'd say typing that every time after rebooting gets a little annoying.

How would I do this every startup / how do I correctly set the gateway? (/etc/rc.local doesn't work)

Comment: I suspect putting that command in `rc.local` doesn't work because you're using Network Manager. Your NIC only gets an IP address after you log into a GUI session (Gnome/KDE/Cinnamon/etc.).

Comment: @Larssend How would I turn off my network manager? (And would it then work to use rc.local?)
Actually, if I'm using a network manager, why is it setting the gateway for ethernet, but not for wifi?

Comment: It is a known behavior of Network Manager. If more than one connections specify a default gateway, only one gets applied to the routing table. Without Network Manager, you will have to configure your connections in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Then your `route` command in `rc.local` will work. Alternatively, you could configure either interface with a static IP in Network Manager and leave the Gateway field blank. This way, you wouldn't need the `route` command in `rc.local`. How to disable Network Manager depends on the distribution.

Comment: If you use `ifdown` (and later `ifup` again), you can put actions into `/etc/network/interfaces` e.g. put `route add default wlan0` into it (I wouldn't use a specific IP there). See `man 5 interfaces` for details.

Comment: Please indicate whether you're using NetworkManager or `/etc/networking/interfaces`, and post your configuration. If you've found a solution, that's great! Please share it by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally got it fixed just by adding
`up route add default gw 192.168.178.1 wlan0`
below my configuration for `wlan0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and it's working (at least until now...).